# Configure Github pull request plugin to work reliably on several builds

Tags: github, build, jenkins, build-automation, pull-request

I have 2 Jenkins instances on two different computers.

One of them deals with Windows and Linux builds, the other deals with OS X builds.

We are working using Github (and more precisely Github pull requests) and so we setup the [Github Pull Request Plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+pull+request+builder+plugin) to automatically launch a build whenever a pull request is made.

It works rather well (the PR status is updated with the build status, that is "pending", "success" or "failure") but sadly, the 3 builds on each platform seem to be unaware of one another. As a result, the following can happen:

```
1: OS X build starts and sets the status to "pending"
2: Windows build starts and sets the status to "pending"
3: OS X build fails and sets the status to "failed"
4: Windows build succeeds and sets the status to "success"
```

Obviously, in this case, the PR will incorrectly be marked as valid, while a build failed. Not awesome. At all.

Would any of you, by any chance have a similar setup (or something close enough) and a way of making this work **reliably** ? Any working solution is fine, including using (an)other plugin(s), changing the physical configuration. Whatever can make things better, as this is currently a nightmare for developers.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this is to configure your GitHub PR builder build as a jenkins build-flow Job:

```
build("unit-tests");
parallel (
    // osx and windows will be scheduled in parallel.
    { build("osx-integration") },
    { build("windows-integration") },
)
```

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin

This way the build-flow job will stay "running" until all builds are finished and fail the entire build if any sub-build fails.

Comment: My understanding is that the build-flow plugin does not use the SCM settings... you'll need a trigger job that then calls you build flow... painful, but classic

Comment: Combined with git plugin build flow plugin is able to be triggered by a push